# Is websockets a good implementation for searchboxes?

Tags: html, search, websocket

Let's say I have a textbox/searchbox

```
<input type="search">
```

then I want to connect it to the server only when the cursor is focused in the searchbox.

The app is intended for Internet-wide use and the searchbox listens to every keypress.

Do you think WebSockets is a good implementation for searchboxes like the above example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what you're saying I am guessing you want to implement something like autocomplete suggestions for the seachbox, or search-as-you-type. In my experience, WebSocket works well for these use cases.

WebSocket is low-latency, so results come back very fast. With a fast back-end and server which is not too far away from the user, you can get near-native-local performance on this.

WebSocket also only consumes bandwidth if there's actual traffic, so you're not paying any traffic penalty for having many searchboxes connected.

I coded a demo applicaton which uses a WebSocket connection to get autocomplete suggestions for a searchbox (searching 1 million records in an Oracle DB backend). The demo is not online at the moment, but you can take a look at the code at https://github.com/tavendo/WebMQDemo/tree/master/web/demo/autocomplete

The WebSocket parts of the demo are very easy to implement. The demo uses AutobahnJS in the browser, which provides some comfort functions on top of raw WebSocket, and implements a PubSub + RPC protocol (WAMP). The code e.g. for the request for autcomplete data is very simple (line 717).

It requires a crossbar.io server and an Oracle DB to run - and the website for the crossbar.io project is currently under construction. So no easy running this at the moment.

**Full disclosure:** I work for Tavendo, which started both the Autobahn and the crossbar.io projects. Both are only given as examples - there is other WebSocket tech out there which you can use. This is just what I'm familiar with.

Comment: Wouldn't having the websocket too fast cause an issue? With http you cancel the previous request when a new one arrives so not to hoard multiple calls, how would you do this in websocket?